# Combinatorics: Prob. to have at least m distinct items that have each been picked at least k times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a set containing $N$ distinct items and draw $n$ times from it *with replacement*.

I would like to find the formula that gives the **probability of getting at least $m$ distinct items that have been picked at least $k$ times each**.

This problem seemed easy at first, but the more I think about it, the more complicated it becomes.

An initial idea was that this problem could be solved like this:
$$P(\text{pick at least m items at least k times each) = }\sum_{i=m}^{n}\sum_{j=k}^nP(\text{pick i items j times each})$$

This is surely not correct though, since I need to take into account impossible combinations of i and j, e.g. if I have 10 draws I cannot have at least 3 balls being picked at least 4 times each.

How could I model this problem?
As I am not a mathematician, I'd appreciate any intiutive explanation in addition to a formal one.

Comment: This is closely related to the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). I'm pretty sure this is a known problem as well, but I cannot recall a name for it.